# Order of arguments in .map() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm curious why the `map()` function in this code works.  Everything I read online says that the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback function expects the first argument to be the `currentValue`, and the second to be the `index`.  If I pass them in that order: `(el, i)`, it doesn't work, but reversing them: `(i, el)` does.

What am I missing here?

```js
$('#works').click( () => {
  var results = $(".myBoxes:checked").map( (i, el)=>el.value).get();

  $('#results').html( results.join(', ') );
});

$('#noWorks').click( () => {
  var results = $(".myBoxes:checked").map( (el, i)=>el.value).get();

  $('#results').html( results.join(', ') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="box1"><input id="box1" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="one"/> Box 1</label>
<label for="box2"><input id="box2" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="two"/> Box 2</label>
<label for="box3"><input id="box3" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="three"/> Box 3</label>
<label for="box4"><input id="box4" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="four"/> Box 4</label>

<br><br>
<button id="works">This works.</button> | 
<button id="noWorks">This doesn't.</button>

<br><br>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using jQuery, which has a *different* structure.

`Array.prototype.map`'s callback's arguments are indeed `(element, index, array)`.

But [`jQuery.prototype.map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/)'s callback's arguments are `(index, element)`.

You have to keep in mind which method you're using.

For an example of using `Array.prototype.map` instead, in your code:

```js
$('#works').click(() => {
  var results = [...$(".myBoxes:checked")].map(el => el.value);

  $('#results').html(results.join(', '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="box1"><input id="box1" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="one"/> Box 1</label>
<label for="box2"><input id="box2" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="two"/> Box 2</label>
<label for="box3"><input id="box3" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="three"/> Box 3</label>
<label for="box4"><input id="box4" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="four"/> Box 4</label>

<br><br>
<button id="works">This works.</button>

<br><br>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Note that `jQuery.map` *does* use `(element, index)` (unlike `jQuery.prototype.map`):

```js
$('#works').click(() => {
  var results = $.map($(".myBoxes:checked"), el => el.value);

  $('#results').html(results.join(', '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="box1"><input id="box1" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="one"/> Box 1</label>
<label for="box2"><input id="box2" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="two"/> Box 2</label>
<label for="box3"><input id="box3" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="three"/> Box 3</label>
<label for="box4"><input id="box4" type="checkbox" class="myBoxes" value="four"/> Box 4</label>

<br><br>
<button id="works">This works.</button>

<br><br>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I knew it would be something simple like that.

Comment: @NinaScholz There are two different types of `.map` with jQuery. One is `$.map` (like a static method), one is `$(something).map` (like a prototype method).

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake people do while using jQuery.
Try to avoid using both plain JS and jQuery at the same time, it is a huge source of errors.

What is happening here is you're using jQuery to get the element (which will give you a jQuery object) but then wanting to use the plain JS map() method.

Take a look at the jQuery method here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/